# How does どうするんだ function here?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases, rhetorical-questions

For more context, see the full text here:
https://www.docdroid.net/RdEh6ZK/img-20170712-0001-new.pdf

Taken from line 3:
すると、一人の男が「そんな物、怖がって**どうするんだ**。...」といばった。

On jisho, どうする translates into "what to do about it" http://jisho.org/search/dousuru
I feel rather unsure about the implementation of this meaning here. 
I'd translate the sentence like this:

"Hereupon, one of the men bragged: "Such things, being afraid what to do about it?..."

I think this phrase goes in the direction of "Such things, why bother with being afraid?" or "such things, what do you do about feeling afraid". The latter would imply a question about what they do to cope with it. 
I would say that the first of the two interpretations is probably more fitting here, but as I said, I don't really know what to do with this どうする here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guy is basically bragging that he is not scared of that "thing", and in a way mock everyone who is scared.

The どうする might not be easy to understand. It technically means,

> "what you gonna do about it",

but the meaning is more something like,

> "how can you keep on going(living your life etc...) if you can't handle this".
>   "What are you gonna do if you can't even handle that".
>   "If you can't manage that much, there is nothing you can do(you are doomed to failure/mediocrity)"

Another easy way to understand might be to see it like this.

> Oh no what shall we do!

Answer (score 10):

It's a rhetorical question (修辞疑問文/反語表現). It's a question in form, but practically serves as an emphatic statement, with no answer or reply expected.

「～～して/でどうする(んだ)？」 as a rhetorical question emphatically asserts 「～～しても意味がない」 "There's no point...", 「～～する必要はない」 "There's no need to...", or 「～～するな」 "Don't..." etc., depending on the context.

> そんな物、怖がって**どうするんだ**。

can mean/imply "There's no point feeling scared of such a thing" 「そんなものを怖がっても意味がない」, "There's no need to be scared of such a thing" 「そんなものを怖がる必要はない」, etc.

Examples:

> - そんな[意気地]{いくじ}のないことで**どうする**
>     Don't be so wet! (from Weblio例文辞典)
> - そんな[狭]{せま}い[了簡]{りょうけん}で**どうする**
>     Have done with such a narrow view! (from Weblio例文辞典)
> - [靴]{くつ}なんか持って**どうすんのさ**！靴下も！
>     Come on just leave your shoes and socks! (from "Spirited Away")

Comment: Few more possible cliches to add to Chocolate's list:

What's up with that!
What's the point!
How could you!
Why would you!

Answer (score 1):

## 日本語

> そんな物、怖がってどうするんだ

質問者も出典を明らかにしておりますが、これは、古典落語の有名な演目の一つである「[まんじゅうこわい](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%98%E3%82%85%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%82%8F%E3%81%84)」の中にでてくるセリフです。

> **【編集による追記】**
> 「怖がる」という行為と、怖がる対象である「そんな物」との関係は相対的である。相対的な関係であるので、「行為」と「対象物」とのいずれか片方だけ大きさあるいは程度を変えるか、両者ともに大きさを変えて「どうするんだ」との意見を述べることが可能である。
> 先に考えた「例示外挿法」と「不用物例示法」の２つに分ける方法は、対象物に着眼した考え方であるが、行為、ここでは「怖がる」という行為の正当性のみに判断の視点を移して「どうするんだ」と意見を述べることもでき、この場合は上記の２つの分類が「そういう行為（怖がるという行為）をすることが正当であるための条件を問う」という視点に統合できることが分かる。
>
> ここで、行為の正当性の条件を問うことを基準に考える統合型を新たに加えるために、前の回答を編集する。
>
> なお、他人の行動を見てなんらかの判断する場合にも、判断する人の性格により、対象となる事象を中心に物事を見るタイプの人と、人の行動には一定の規範があるという前提で物事を見るタイプの人（「べきである」という考え方の人）がいるので、どちらの見方が正しいとは言えない。結果として、「そんな物、怖がってどうするんだ」いう意味も視点を変えると自ずと解釈（行間に含まれる発言者の意図）が異なる。

質問者の挙げた例題、またChocolateさんが回答の中で挙げた例題をよく見ると、「～して（または　～で）どうする」という表現の用法または意味は１つではなく、次のように大きく２つに分類できることが分かります。

グループ１

例示されている事象・事物は、行動を引き起こす条件である。

- そんな物、怖がってどうするんだ。
- そんな意気地のないことでどうする。
- そんな狭い了簡でどうする。
- そんなところで躓（つまづ）いてどうする。

グループ２

例示されている事象・事物は、行動の対象物である。

- 靴なんか持ってどうすんのさ！
- 【地震の揺れが収まった屋外での会話】枕なんか持ち出してどうするんだ。

いずれも対象者の行動を非難するか揶揄（やゆ）していますが、揶揄した理由がグループ１では、「対象者がとった行動がそれをするのに値しない対象物に対してであったので、今は目の前にないが、本当にその行動をするのに値する対象物が現れたときに、対象者に対してそのときは『どうするのだ』と言い、こんな程度の低いものに対して今からそんな行動をとっていては早すぎるし、先が思いやられるね」というような意味合いです。
いい表現方法がないので、私は「**例示外挿法**」とでも便宜的に呼びます。
質問者が提示した「そんな物、怖がってどうするんだ」はこのグループに入ります。

> **外挿**（がいそう、英: **extrapolation**、**補外**とも言う）とは、簡単な日本語がありませんが、ある既知の数値データを基にして、そのデータの範囲の外側で予想される数値を求めること。 またその手法を外挿法（補外法）といいます。

一方グループ２は、「対象者がとった行動そのものがそれをするのに値しない、あるいは役に立たないことを揶揄しており、例示外挿法と違って、その値しない行動そのものに対して「どうするんだ」と言っております。」「例示外挿法」に対して「**不用物例示法**」とでも呼びたいと思います。

いずれも、対象者の現在取った行動に対しての評価ですが、評価尺度の基準は話者の基準あるいは、対象者、話者を含めた会話が成り立っている環境でのものですが、対象者の成熟度によって基準は変わります。

例えばアルピニストが十分な装備をしてこれから出発しようというときに、家の前の縁石に躓（つまづ）いて転びそうになったら、「 そんなところで躓（つまづ）いてどうする。」となります。
これは、「こらから険しい岩山を踏破しようとする人が、そんな低い縁石で躓いていたら、本当の岩山に遭遇したらどうするのだ」という意味を含んでおります。「どうする」は縁石から外挿した転んでも致し方のない険しい岩山を想定しての表現です。

一方、よちよち歩きの幼児が同じ縁石に躓いて転んだ光景では、縁石の高さ（険しさ）がその幼児が転んでも正当化される基準を満たしておりますので、「 そんなところで躓（つまづ）いてどうする」という表現は使えません。

グループ２の例文を見ますと、現在の事象を外挿することなく、事象そのものに対する対象者の行動が「意味がない」「役立たない」と揶揄されていることが、グループ１と比較すると明瞭でしょう。

「靴なんか持ってどうすんのさ！」は、「なんの役にも立たない靴なんか持って何に使うつもり？」と言う意味であり、「枕なんか持ち出してどうするんだ。」は、「家の権利書や貯金通帳ならわかるが、一銭の値打ちもない枕なんかを持ち出して何をしようとしているの（あるいは、何の役に立てようとしているの）？」というような意味です。

最初の質問にある「そんな物、怖がってどうするんだ。」は、「**そんな**（しょうがない/つまらない）**物**（を）**、怖がって**（いては、本当に怖いものが来たときは）**どうするんだ**」という意味で「そんな」から「本当に怖いもの」を外挿しております。

「そんな意気地のないことでどうする。」は、「日本を背負って立つと宣言したお前が、一人で行くのは怖いよと言っているようでは、お前の宣言するような大事な局面を前にしたらお前はどう行動するつもりだ」と窘（たしな）めており、目の前の少しは怖いかもしれない事象から誰もが怖気（おじけ）づくような「大事」を外挿しております。

「そんな狭い了簡でどうする。」は、外挿で想像できるものは誰もが認める高僧や聖人のような寛大な人あるいはその人の慈悲に満ちた寛大な行動ですが、それを目指している駆け出しの修行者が我が子のちょとしたいたずらを顔を真っ赤にして怒っている現実の振る舞いを見た先輩修行者から発せられた言葉のような気もします。

[image]

---

### 【べき論統合型】

結果として、Chocolateさんの回答にあるrhetorical question (修辞疑問文/反語表現)に近いものかなと思う。

- **そんな物、怖がってどうするんだ。**　そんな物つならないものを怖がって何をするつもりだ。それは違うだろう。怖がる**べき**ものは（怖がっても正当化できる（致し方のない）ものは）、もっと違うもの（怖いもの）だろう。
- **そんな意気地のないことでどうする。**　（こんなちっぽけな局面で）そんな意気地のない行動をとってどうするつもりだ。それは違うだろう。意気地のない行動をとる**べき**ものは（意気地のない行動をとっても正当化できる（致し方のない）ものは）、もっと違う局面（大事な局面）だろう。
- **そんな狭い了簡でどうする。**　そんな狭い了簡でどうするつもりだ。それは違うだろう。狭い了簡である**べき**ものは（狭い了簡と言われても正当化できる（致し方のない）ものは）、相手がもっと酷（ひど）い（相手の了簡がもっと狭い）場合ぐらいだろう。
- **そんなところで躓（つまづ）いてどうする。**　そんな（簡単な）ところで躓（つまづ）いてどうするつもりだ。それは違うだろう。躓（つまづ）く**べき**ものは（躓いても正当化できる（致し方のない）ものは）、もっと違うところ（もっと険しいところ、もっと段差のあるところ）だろう。
- **靴なんか持ってどうすんのさ！**　靴なんか（役立たないもの）を持ってどうすんのか。それは違うだろう。持つ**べき**ものは（持っても正当化できる（咎（とが）められないものは）、もっと違うもの（役立つもの、価値のあるもの）だろう。
- **【地震の揺れが収まった屋外での会話】枕なんか持ち出してどうするんだ。**　枕なんか持ち出してどうするのだ。それは違うだろう。持ち出す**べき**ものは（持ち出しても正当化できるものは）、もっと別のもの（家の権利証や貯金通帳のような値打ちのあるもの）だろう。

## English

> **そんな　物、　怖がって　どうするんだ**

有名な落語のセリフですね。
*It is a line of a famous Rakugo, isn't it?*

> **そんな**（しょうがない/つまらない）**物**（を）**、怖がって**（いては、本当に怖いものが来たときは）**どうするんだ**
> *What are you gonna do, what if really scary things come to you who is scared of such a trivial thing like that?*

The lines continue as follows:

俺が本当に怖いのは、饅頭｛まんじゅう｝だよ。
*What I am really scared of is a manju.*

俺を本当に怖がらせたいのなら、饅頭をもって来い。
*Bring me a manju if you wanna make me really scared.*

**Manju** is a Japanese steamed bun with a bean‐jam filling; It is very delicious.

[image]