# What does 面と向かってどうするってんだ mean

Tags: grammar, meaning, rhetorical-questions

Looking at other posts I found [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/50318/how-does-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0-function-here) meaning of どうする and was wondering whether this is the same meaning and how the ってんだ changes it compared to if he said 面と向かってどうする. I am guessing the difference is that どうする would just be simply saying something like "there is no point in doing that", whilst どうするってんだ would be more like "what point are you saying there is in doing that".

> 「だって、見なかったことに……なんて言ったってさぁ。絶対思いだすよ。それなら隠れて思いだされるより面と向かっての方がいいもん」
>
> 「気持ちはわからんでもないが、**面と向かってどうするってんだ**」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your understanding is correct. ってんだ after a dictionary-form is short for って言うんだ, which is colloquialism for と言うのだ. This どうする is a rhetorical question.

- 面と向かって "face-to-face", "while facing"
- どうする "what will you do"
- ってんだ "do you say"

> 面と向かってどうするってんだ
>   (Literally) What do you say are you doing face-to-face?

The actual implication is "there is no point in doing something face-to-face."